# Insert new data to a blank row in core data

Tags: core-data

I want to add data (string) to one of the blank row in core data (iOS). How do you do that?

e.g : I have an entity of STUDENTS and in that entity has 3 attributes : index, name, age. the 3 attributes are filled with data, let's say it has 10 row of data. But on index 9 the attribute of name has no data (blank space). How do you fill that blank space ?

I can't describe it clearly because I can't upload an image yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't think of `Core Data` as a database with rows and columns.  It is an `Object Graph and Persistence framework`.  So you deal with Objects (like rows) and object properties (like columns).  So once you have fetched or created some objects you set their properties.

If you haven't created `NSManagedObject` subclasses from your object model then you have to use the `KVC` accessors:

```
[student10 setValue:@"William" forKey:@"name"];
```

If you do create subclasses you can use `Objective-C` properties.

```
student10.name = @"William";
```

I recommend reading more about `Core Data` in the Apple Documentation to gain a proper understanding of the framework.  They also have some tutorials I think.